# Customize UI dialogs in wix Bootstrapper installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

We have developed installer packages for multiple applications using wix installer template project of visual studio.

We merged all the installer packages in one single wix bootstraper project to install all the application with single installer. It works fine.

Now we want to customize UI(Add new custom dialogs, customize installation sequence) of bootstraper project to select which application needs to be install etc.

Comment: Will you be using a C# of C++ bootstrapper? You can download the wix source here and go through the burn project to see how they implement the UI of their bootstrapper. https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/BalExtension wixstdba is the unmanaged bootstrapper and mba is the managed bootstrapper. This is a **very** broad question and I don't think you will be able to find a suitable answer through stackoverflow it is just to big of a subject for this platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wixwpf](https://wixwpf.codeplex.com/) to customize Burn UI, instead of writing everything from scratch.There are couple of  [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQspLgRUPFU) youtube how to use it. Hope this helps. I had tried wixwpf few months back, it makes your life easy.

Comment: Your links seem to be dead and the WixWPF project moved over to github.

https://github.com/nickguletskii/WixWPFWizardBA